# Azure Function App AzureWebJobsStorage vs WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, app-config

The Azure function app [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings) lists two app settings which seem identical to me.

> **AzureWebJobsStorage**
>
> The Azure Functions runtime uses this storage account connection string for normal operation. Some uses of this storage account include key management, timer trigger management, and Event Hubs checkpoints. The storage account must be a general-purpose one that supports blobs, queues, and tables.

> **WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING**
>
> Connection string for storage account where the function app code and configuration are stored in event-driven scaling plans.

It seems both point to the storage account the function uses to store its files.

So, what is the difference between them and do I need both of them?

Comment: The storage account specified by `AzureWebJobsStorage` won't be used for storing content files, but `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` will be.

Comment: We only need to explicitly set the value for AzureWebJobsStorage but not for WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING. I believe the Azure function sets the value for WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING internally using AzureWebJobsStorage.

Comment: @Dai, what would "content files" be?

Comment: @Inshallah The files in your application: `.dll`, `.html`, `.cshtml`, `.png`, `.css`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Dai and @Nadeem Khan

`AzureWebJobsStorage`:

- As Mentioned in the [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings)

  > The Azure Functions runtime uses this storage account connection string for normal operation. Some uses of this storage account include key management, timer trigger management, and Event Hubs checkpoints. The storage account must be a general-purpose one that supports blobs, queues, and tables.
- It is used to configure the Azure Functions runtime to store internal operational data, such as function triggers, checkpoints, and logs. It also serves as the default storage account for your functions if you don't specify a specific storage account for a function.
- It should be set to a connection string for an Azure Storage account (usually a blob storage account). This storage account is used for maintaining the state and coordination of your function app.

`WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING`:

- It is used for Azure Functions running in a Consumption Plan when you need to enable read-only access to files in a file share. For both Windows and Linux. For reference check this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code?tabs=bicep#create-a-function-app).
- It should be set to a connection string that points to an Azure File Storage account. A file share will be created in the storage account.

**Summary,**

`AzureWebJobsStorage` is primarily used for internal Azure Functions operational data and can be any Azure Storage account, while `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` is used specifically for read-only access to files in Azure File Storage when you're using the Consumption Plan. It is created in Consumption and Elastic premium plan only as mentioned in [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring).

I have create three Function of each app service plan. You can see `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` available in Consumption and Elastic Premium Plan

**appsettingfunc** with **Consumption Plan**:

[image]

**appsettingfuncnon-consumption** with **Basic Plan**:

[image]

**appsettingfunc-premium** with **Elastic Premium Plan**:

[image]